# rails receiving webhook between two localhosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, webhooks

I have an rails app that sends a webhook (localhost:3000) with data. Before, I used a online webhook monitor (Pipedream) but I want now to build a second rails app to receive the data (localhost:3000 -> localhost:3300). I've created a route /webhook/receive and the controller for it but get nothing from localhost:3000.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thats on my first app:

```
def send_create_webhook(webhook_url)
 company = User.find_by(email: 'test1@test.de').company_account
 webhook_url = 'tcp://0.0.0.0:3300/data/receive'

 SendWebhookJob.perform_later(webhook_url, {
      subscription: {
          type: "#{@tool.title} successfully subscribed",
          date: "#{Time.zone.now}",
          subscribed: Time.now.strftime("%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %Z"),
          user: {
              company: "#{company.title}",
              name: current_user.name,
              email: current_user.email,
          }
      }
  })
end


class SendWebhookJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  WEBHOOK_RETRIES = 3

  def perform(webhook_url, data, retry_count = 0)
    p "COUNT #{retry_count} : #{Time.zone.now} : Sending data to #{webhook_url}"

    # make a request
    begin
      response = HTTP.post(webhook_url, json:data)
      successful = response.code == 200
    rescue StandardError => e
      successful = false
    end

    if successful
      p "SUCCESSFUL WEBHOOK"
    elsif retry_count < WEBHOOK_RETRIES
      wait = 2 ** retry_count
      SendWebhookJob.set(wait: wait.seconds).perform_later(webhook_url, data,retry_count + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

The second app I just created:

```
resources :data do
 get :receive
 post :receive
end

def DataController < ApplicationController
 require "http"

 def receive
  response = HTTP.get('tcp://0.0.0.0:3000')
 end

end
```

Comment: Show what you are doing to call webhook

Comment: added the code into my question @AmitPatel

Comment: First step is, replace `tcp:` with `http:` and see if second app receives any request?

Comment: no doesn't work @AmitPatel :S

Comment: HTTP is a different protocol than TCP which is the low level transport protocol. If you're doing a webhook its should be communicating via HTTP/HTTPS. Don't do HTTP calls in your controller - that should be done in a service object / job.

Comment: @max okay but I only get the data from localhost:3000 to do some code of it around. It's only an application for testing. When I do the post method from webhook I get an 400 error

Comment: Did you actually take any troubleshooting steps like using cURL to test that http://localhost:3030/recieve is responding? All you're telling us is basically "didn't work" which is completely useless information.

Comment: Show us logs or anything actually useful so we can see whats happing.

Comment: no I didnt try... have not experience with cURL or consuming requests from a -> b

Comment: How do you expect to do something this complex without any basic troubleshooting tools? Start by learning to use cURL or Postman. Its not rocket science.

Comment: Performing SendWebhookJob (Job ID: 1da6b68c-1eba-4843-8408-2731d47ca5bf) from Async(default) enqueued at 2020-04-07T14:08:44Z with arguments: "http:://0.0.0.0:3300/data/receive", {:subscription=>{:type=>"tool successfully subscribed", :date=>"2020-04-07 14:08:41 UTC", :subscribed=>"2020-07-04 16:08:41 CEST", :user=>{:company=>"Test GmbH", :name=>"test", :email=>"test1@test.de"}}}, 3
"COUNT 3 : 2020-04-07 14:08:48 UTC : Sending data to http:://0.0.0.0:3300/data/receive"
"response = 400"

Comment: I used postman to fetch data from my api via doorkeeper. My webhookjob was successfully post data to pipedream... Just want to do the "same" like pipedream do for me

Comment: It could be that you're doing a Post request without a CSRF token. The logs on the `:3030` server should tell you more. It could also be that you're not sending a `content-type` header and a body full of JSON and rails is receiving it as form data.

Comment: Okay it works now I get an response on 3300... The problem was in the rest of my data_controller. Happened bcs of doing scaffolding